# Create an entry in openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I installed openldap on windows 7. I started the server fine. I added an entry in init.ldif file. How can add this entry to the server. What is the exact command to do so.

Also, I would like to know if there is any client for openldap in windows where I can directly add/modify/delet entries in the ldap server?

EDIT:

I got the command to run, and when I run it I get a message 'bdb DB_CONFIG file not found', so I created one such file with data I got by googling around the file name and stored it under /data directory and yet i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [ldapadd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapadd) (or [ldapmodify](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapmodify)) program -- See the linked manpages for syntax and examples.  Also refer to [The OpenLDAP FAQ-O-Matic](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1.html), [admin guide](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/) and [Quick Start Guide](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html).
If this is your first time setting up and using OpenLDAP I suggest working through the examples step by step at first.

Re: the error in your question update, this should not be a fatal condition (If I remember correctly it is a warning, not an error).  If your update is not working we'll need more information in order to troubleshoot (assuming I'm remembering this message correctly).

As for picking a client to use from Windows, there are many LDAP clients - [This is the canonical one](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tools/13765.html): It's written in Java and runs pretty much everywhere.  There are many better ones out there - Ask Google, try a few, and pick the one you like best.